# jQuery .data() not working along with .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the content of `data-title` of `div` with `id="shirt"` which is `Shirt Front` and alert when the button checkout is clicked. It does not work.

**jQuery snippet**:

```
var bandcolor='';
var facecolor='';

$("#shirt").click(function(){
    bandcolor=$("#shirt").data("title");
});

$("#checkout-button").click(function(){
    alert(bandcolor);
});
```

**HTML snippet**:

```
<div id="main-container" class="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="fpd">
            <div class="fpd-product" id="shirt" data-title="Shirt Front" data- thumbnail="images/hoodie/Black.png">
                 <img src="images/hoodie/Black.png" data-title="Shirt Front"  />
```

You can check out my web site at http://www.shivsample.comlu.com. The `div` with `id="shirt"` is the first image on the left hand panel.

**The full html code is as follows**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Fancy Product Designer</title>

<!-- Style sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-   1.9.2.custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spectrum.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancyProductDesigner.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancyProductDesigner-fonts.css" />

<!-- Include js files -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/spectrum.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/hammer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.hammer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancyProductDesigner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {



        var bandcolor='';
             var facecolor='';
            $("#shirt").click(function(){
                bandcolor=$("#shirt").data("title");
                });
            $("#checkout-button").click(function(){
            alert(bandcolor);
                });



        //call the plugin and save it in a variable to have access to the API
        var fpd = $('#fpd').fancyProductDesigner({
            editorMode: false,
            fonts: ['Arial', 'Helvetica', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana',   'Geneva', 'Fearless'],
            //these are the parameters for the text that is added via  the "Add Text" button
            customTextParamters: {x: 210, y: 250, colors: "#000000",  removable: true, resizable: true, draggable: true, rotatable: true}
        })
        .data('fancy-product-designer');





    });


</script>



</head>

<body>
    <div id="main-container" class="container" >      
    <div id="content">
        <div id="fpd" >
            <div class="fpd-product" id="shirt" data-title="Shirt Front" data-thumbnail="images/hoodie/Black.png">
                <img src="images/hoodie/Black.png" data-title="Shirt Front"  />

            </div>



            <div class="fpd-product" id="shirt2" data-title="Shirt  Front1" data-thumbnail="images/hoodie/Camo.png">
                <img src="images/hoodie/Camo.png" title="Base Front"  />

            </div>

            <div class="fpd-design">
                <img src="images/designs/swirl.png" title="Swirl"  />
                <img src="images/designs/swirl2.png" title="Swirl 2" />
                <img src="images/designs/swirl3.png" title="Swirl 3"  />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="api-buttons clearfix" style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="#" id="print-button" class="btn btn-info">Print</a>
            <a href="#" id="checkout-button" class="btn btn-  success">Checkout</a>
            <span class="pull-right price badge badge-inverse"><span  id="thsirt-price"></span> $</span>
        </div>
        <div id="thsirt-output" class="output"></div>
       </div>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to be more speceific please. it helps to see where the mistake is faster

Comment: Take array object instead of single variable!

Comment: I could be wrong, but the first image in the left column does not have the ID `shirt`, and the data-title is `undefined` ?

Comment: @adeneo Image is wrapped inside `div` and that `div` has ID `shirt`

Comment: hey thanks for the immediate replies. @Dhaval can you try doing this with a single variable?

Comment: what does `$(document).ready(function () { alert($("#shirt").data("title")); });` give you?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray it returns "Shirt Front"

Comment: Excellect so *jquery .data* does work - try again with the title of your question ;)

Comment: @ChrisMoutray thank you :) .data does work . but, .click and .data together seems to be a problem here. any solutions?

Comment: what happens when you try with bandcolor=$("#shirt").attr("data-title"); this code. i am referring to your ocmment above. click and .data together.

Comment: @shanavascet  yes i tried it. But returns nothing .

Comment: There's no DIV with that ID wrapping the image, one of your plugins is changing the markup, use inspect element in the console

Comment: A simple fiddle works (without your other plugins) http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/6sZ96/

Comment: this.addDesign=function(a,b,c)
{L.prepend("<li></li>").children("li:first").append('<img src="'+a+'" title="'+b+'" />').click(function(){
var a=e(this).children("img");
p.addElement("image",a.attr("src"),a.attr("title"),a.data("parameters"));return!1}).children("img").data("parameters",c)};

Comment: This is the snippet from the plugin which might be causing the problem.  @adeneo